# I would like to remove hash in Azurefd url

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

Hi I would like to change azure front door endpoint url from myendpoint-mdjf2jfgjf82mnzx.z01.azurefd.net to myendpoint.azurefd.net

Is it possible?

I tried to read document and saw about add custom urls but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to "remove the hash" from the Front Door URL?  Is there a business reason, or do you just want the URL to be prettier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use a custom domain with an Azure Front Door endpoint you must control the target domain.  Microsoft doesn't allow you to customize the name of your default Front Door endpoint URL on their azurefd.net subdomain.

For example you can create a new subdomain on a domain you control and then assign that custom hostname to the Front Door endpoint.  If you owned "contoso.com" you could create a "frontdoorendpoint.contoso.com" DNS entry with your DNS provider and then associate it with Front Door as described in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain).

Since "azurefd.net" is controlled by Microsoft you can't create/register a "myendpoint.azurefd.net" subdomain with the public internet.